# Exported PDF's font

Tags: fonts, pdf

I'm sorry if this is basic, but I've searched a lot and found none.

Is there a way to change the font that appears on the PDF? To Nanumgothic specifically? I've tried with TeXmaker and Texworks and couldn't figure how to do that...